# Update 12 records in a database table in less than 13 queries

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I've got a database table in my application called "periods". The structure of the table is:

- Year (Number)
- Month (Number)
- Period (Text)

The Year column stores years (Say, 2016), Month stores months (1-12), and period stores the period of the month/year - eg; November 2016 = 11/16, so period = 1116.

In the table, it stores from 2016, to 2030, so 14 years worth.

In my code I currently have the following `Try` statement on my main forms `Load` event. The aim of this code is that on the 1st January each year, the table updates and sets the Year column to 15 years in advance where year = current year -1, and then creates the periods.

It currently uses one update for each record - Is there a way I can reduce the code here to less queries, but still get the desired effect?

For instance, 01/01/2017 will set all Year values to 2031 WHERE Year = 2016, and then (this is the part I struggled with), set the periods to correspond with the month and year of that record?

```vb
Try
    Dim current As String = Convert.ToString(Date.Today)
    Dim year As String = Convert.ToString(Date.Today.AddYears(-1).Year)
    Dim nextyear As String = Convert.ToString(Date.Today.AddYears(15).Year)
    Dim period As String
    current = current.Substring(0, 5)
    period = nextyear.Substring(2, 2)

      If current = "01/01" Then
         trans = con.BeginTransaction()
         sql = "UPDATE [periods] SET [year] = ? WHERE [year] = ?"

         Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@y", OleDbType.Integer).Value = year
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         sql = "UPDATE [periods] SET [period] = ? WHERE [month] = ? AND [year] = ?"

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "01" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 1
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "02" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 2
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "03" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 3
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "04" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 4
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "05" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 5
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "06" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 6
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "07" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 7
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "08" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 8
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "09" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 9
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "10" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 10
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "11" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 11
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "12" & period
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 12
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

         trans.Commit()

     Else
     End If

 Catch ex As Exception
    trans.Rollback()
     silentErrorLog(ex)

  End Try
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> Dim current As String = Convert.ToString(Date.Today)
> Dim year As String = Convert.ToString(Date.Today.AddYears(-1).Year)
> Dim nextyear As String = Convert.ToString(Date.Today.AddYears(15).Year)
> Dim period As String
> current = current.Substring(0, 5)
> period = nextyear.Substring(2, 2)
> ```

It's not clear why you would want to work with `String` variables, given...

> ```
> cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
> ```

The database wants an `Integer` type, so the `Convert.ToString` conversions are useless at best, since you're going to be boxing the value type into an `Object` anyway.

```
Dim current As Date = Date.Today
Dim year As Integer = Date.Today.AddYears(-1).Year
Dim nextyear As Integer = Date.Today.AddYears(15).Year
```

It's not clear what's going on with the next two instructions:

> ```
> current = current.Substring(0, 5)
> period = nextyear.Substring(2, 2)
> ```

First, that's re-assigning `current`, which has been assigned a value that was never used. Next, these assignments are extracting specific parts of a `Date` represented as a `String`, but you have no control on that representation - your code might work in an *en-US* locale, but produce nonsense results in a *fr-FR* or *en-CA* locale.

I'm not sure what the value of `current` should be after that second assignment. Assuming say `2016/11/02` (or would it be `11/02/2016`?) so the 5 left-most characters would be either `2016/` or `11/02` (or `02/11`?), and we have no way of telling by just reading the code.

The `period` would be `11` I guess (I'm starting to presume your date format looks like `02/11/2016`), but then again I can't be 100% sure just by reading the code.

It's not clear why *next year* would be 15 years from now either: I find `year`, `nextyear` and `current` could use better, more descriptive and less misleading names.

Now, without changing the actual SQL queries, you code could use a loop, to parameterize the `@period` value:

```
For month = 1 To 12
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = String.Format("{0:D2}{1}", month, period)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = month
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

Now, this will clean up your code *a lot*, but will *still* send 12 queries to the database server.

Looks like you can derive the `@period` parameter from the `@month` value, right?

```
sql = "UPDATE [periods] SET [period] = [month] WHERE [year] = ?"
```

Of course that won't work as-is. But the point is that you'll want to tweak the `period` assignment to derive its value from the `month` field on the same record, using data that's already in the database. That way you'll update all records for the specified `year` in a single query.

---

You haven't shown where the `con` object is initialized or closed, but it should be in a `Using` block, so that it's properly closed and released when you're done with it. Same with the `OleDbCommand` instances: the class implements the `IDisposable` interface, so you should either explicitly call `.Dispose`, or wrap its usage in a `Using` scope. Doing that would also make your code more sane - by reusing the `cmd` object you're giving it a new meaning everytime, which is never a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted! I considered a `For Loop` but wasn't sure how to create the period value in a parameter. My date formats are UK, dd/MM/yyyy, so current would get the dd/MM value (For the `If` clause), year would be the year just passed (2015, if it was 01/01/2016), and nextyear is a bit misleading, but 14 years worth are stored in the DB currently, so adding 15 years adds on the next set of years/periods. The period value is to get the yy part of the period, by substringing the current year. Could have done things differently, though, in hindsight.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I thought when I read your question is that the Period column should either be a computed column or not a column at all (with it being generated as necessary in stored procedures or select statements). The Period column will never be a value that cannot be easily computed from the other two columns. If it must be a column, why not make it a computed column with the formula (right('0'+cast([Month] as varchar(2)),2)+right([Year],2)) ?

Then the yearly update statement only needs to update the Year field for those 12 records that correspond to the previous year.

Edit: I see now this is MS Access, where I was thinking SQL Server 2000 for some reason. It still applies, but in Access it's called a calculated field, and the formula will need to change to something like FORMAT([Month],"00") & Right(String([Year]),2)

Answer (score 2):

In VB.NET 14 (for VS2015) you can use String interpolation and make your code a lot cleaner ([For Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31342465/1214743))

you could write the loop, that Mat's Mug talks about, like this:

```
For month = 1 To 12
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con, trans)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = $"{month:D2}{period}"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = month
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = nextyear
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

With String Interpolation (in VB and C# at least) you can include your formatting in the variable call using the Colon just like you would in a string.format method call.  This is really the exact same thing as using the String.Format except shorter.